# Unable to install tables (Python, OS X) - could not find a local HDF5 installation

Tags: python, macos, hdf5

I keep having an error

```
ERROR:: Could not find a local HDF5 installation
```

when I'm installing tables in Python:

```
pip install tables
```

I've downloaded and installed http://continuum.io/downloads but it didn't help. What else can I try to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the anaconda distribution you can just do:

```
$ conda install pytables
```

If you **need** to install from pip and already have the HDF5 libraries installed you can do:

```
$ HDF5_DIR=/path/to/hdf5 pip install tables
```

E.g. you could install HDF5 with conda and still install pytables using the method above but it's a lot easier just using conda.

Answer (score 5):

On mac os arm chip:

```
brew install hdf5
HDF5_DIR=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hdf5/1.12.2_2 pip install tables
```

And you are done!

Answer (score 0):

On osx without installing anaconda:

```
brew install homebrew/science/hdf5
pip install tables
```

Comment: : homebrew/science was deprecated. This tap is now empty and all its contents were either deleted or migrated.